# Spring Integration DSL - Wiretap doesn't run asynchronously

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-integration, dsl

As Spring Integration document states (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-wiretap), if we want wiretap to run as async, we need to send messages to asynchronous Channel (Pollable Channel or Executor Channel)

I tried to implement a flow like below but it does not run as expect

```
return IntegrationFlows
     .from("inputChannel")
     .wireTap(customChannel())
     .handle((p, h) -> {
          System.out.println("After calling wiretap");
          return p;
     })
     .get();
=========================

@Bean
public MessageChannel customChannel() {

    return MessageChannels.executor(new TaskExecutor() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable task) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            System.out.println("End customChannel");
        }
    }).get();
}
```

I expect it will write "After calling wiretap", and then sleep 5 seconds, and then write "End customChannel"

But the console is:

```
End customChannel
After calling wiretap
```

Please help to give me the suggestion for this case!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find the way to execute asynchronously like below

```
return IntegrationFlows
 .from("inputChannel")
 .wireTap("CustomChannel")
 .handle((p, h) -> {
      System.out.println("After calling wiretap");
      return p;
 })
 .get();
```

=========================

```
@Bean (value = "CustomChannel")
public MessageChannel customChannel() {
    // execute 5 concurrent threads.
    // if additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue.
    return new ExecutorChannel(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "CustomChannel")
public MessageHandler exportDataServiceActivator() {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            // TODO Handle logic we want here

        }
    };
}
```